# How can I fetch list with getbyname

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have people with the same name in my table. I want the information of people with the same name as getby name to come.

```
 private static List<Personel> _personeller = new List<Personel> {
   new Personel{Id=1,Ad="Cagatay",Soyad="Kızıltan",TcKimlikNo="11111111",DogumTarihi= new DateTime(1993,1,22) },
   new Personel{Id=2,Ad="Ali",Soyad="Kızıltan",TcKimlikNo="11111112",DogumTarihi=new DateTime(1992,1,22) },
   new Personel{Id=3,Ad="Ali",Soyad="Kızıl",TcKimlikNo="11111113",DogumTarihi= new DateTime(1991,1,22)},
   new Personel{Id=4,Ad="Ahmet",Soyad="Kızıltan",TcKimlikNo="11111113",DogumTarihi= new DateTime(1990,1,22)}
};
```

```
public ActionResult PersonelAra()
  {
  return View();
  }
```

```
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "PersonelAra";
  }

<h2>Personel Ara</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
  <input type="text" name="personelAdi" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
  }
```

```
public class Personel
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string Ad { get; set; }

      public string Soyad { get; set; }

      public string TcKimlikNo { get; set; }

      public DateTime DogumTarihi { get; set; }
 
   }
```

```
[HttpGet]
  public ActionResult PersonelAramaSonucu(string personelAdi)
  {

   var aramaSonucundakiPersoneller = _personeller.Where(p => p.Ad.Contains(personelAdi)).ToList();

   return View(aramaSonucundakiPersoneller);

 }
```

Currently, when I enter the name of Ali, only the first person information is displayed.

```
{Id=2,Ad="Ali",Soyad="Kızıltan",TcKimlikNo="11111112",DogumTarihi=new DateTime(1992,1,22) },
```

what i want should be like this:

```
{Id=2,Ad="Ali",Soyad="Kızıltan",TcKimlikNo="11111112",DogumTarihi=new DateTime(1992,1,22) },
{Id=3,Ad="Ali",Soyad="Kızıl",TcKimlikNo="11111113",DogumTarihi= new DateTime(1991,1,22)},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to try this way ? Below is a work demo, hope it can help you.

In Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PersonelAramaSonucu(string personelAdi)
        {

            var aramaSonucundakiPersoneller = _personeller.Where(p => p.Ad.Contains(personelAdi)).ToList();

            return Json(aramaSonucundakiPersoneller);

        }
```

In PersonelAra.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PersonelAra";
}

<h2>Personel Ara</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonelAramaSonucu", "Getbyname", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" name="personelAdi" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
}
```

result:

[image]

**OR**

use `return View(aramaSonucundakiPersoneller);` in your PersonelAramaSonucu method.

In the PersonelAramaSonucu.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Personel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <strong>Id: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    <br />
    <strong>Ad: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ad)
    <br />
    <strong>Soyad : </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Soyad)
    <br />
    <strong>TcKimlikNo : </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TcKimlikNo)
    <br />
    <strong>DogumTarihi : </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DogumTarihi)
    <br />
}
```

result:

[image]

**Update**

I based on [this project](https://github.com/WolfgangOfner/.NetCoreRepositoryAndUnitOfWorkPattern)  to create a `Task<ActionResult<List<Customer>>> GetCustomerByFirstName(string firstName)` method.

In  CustomerController :

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Customer>>> GetCustomerByFirstName(string firstName)
        {
            return await _customerService.GetCustomerByFirstNameAsync(firstName);
        }
```

In CustomerRepository:

```
 public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomerByFirstNameAsync(string firstName)
        {
            return await GetAll().Where(x => x.FirstName == firstName).ToListAsync();
            
        }
```

Define the `Task<ActionResult<List<Customer>>> GetCustomerByFirstName(string firstName)` method in service,iservice,repository,irepository like others method in  the project , and note the `name="personelAdi"` in PersonelAra, I change to `name="firstName"`.

result:
[image]

Comment: you are great. thank you very much. So how can I integrate this process into the layered architecture? can you help me? How can I create methods on service,iservice,repository,irepository pages?

Comment: @kocakh Please see my update. Note I refer to the [project](https://github.com/WolfgangOfner/.NetCoreRepositoryAndUnitOfWorkPattern) to add a method,  at the same time I use database, you can use your data.

Comment: hello, I added my question as an answer, I'm asking for your help @Qing Guo

Comment: @kocakh You can create a new post, and describe your question clear, so that we all  can help you.

Comment: hello, last time I checked, everything seemed to be fine, but I get an error like this: for example, I'm importing contacts named ali and 2 records should arrive. 2 records are coming, but 2 of them are the same as the first record. that is, he writes the first data he sees, no matter how many. how can i fix this please help. :(  @Qing Guo

Comment: @kocakh " but 2 of them are the same as the first record."  what do you mean? In the picture I can get two different data, but the same Ali.

Comment: @kocakh Could you share your code and picture ?

Comment: I updated can you check? @Qing Guo

Comment: Hello again, I have a question if you have time. I have a service application that I received from another place. I want to integrate this service reference into my own project. So I want the data in that service to be returned. I added the reference but I don't know what to do next

Comment: @kocakh I have see your new post, I think you can try to search  "Consuming WCF Services in .NET Core " .